# Validating Multiple Roles in Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization, intercept

I have added all the required libs and dependencies for the security and the application is working for single role & Any role cases

Single:
`<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('enabled')" />`

Any Role 
`<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('enabled','view')" />`

is there are way to check multiple(AND or All Roles) roles using the expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('enabled') and hasRole('view')" />
```

Comment: Thanks , that worked !!! - expression was able execute, <sec:authorize access="hasAuthority('enabled') and hasAuthority('view')"> works too